# Timespan not showing up

Tags: c#, winforms, timespan

I cannot seem to get my code to calculate the amount of minutes between 2 datetime fields:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string startTime = "5/1/2008 1:00:00 PM";
    string endTime = "5/1/2008 3:00:00 PM";

    DateTime startTimeParse = 
        DateTime.Parse(startTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime endTimeParse = 
        DateTime.Parse(endTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    MessageBox.Show(startTime);
    MessageBox.Show(endTime);

    TimeSpan result = endTimeParse - startTimeParse;
    int hours = result.Hours;
    int minutes = result.Minutes;
}
```

In debug the result is just `00:00:00`

If you can show me how to MessageBox.show the different in mins?

Comment: What do you mean with "the result"? What are the values of `hours` and `minutes` in above example?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. `Hours` will be 2 and `Minutes` will be `0`.

Comment: the result should be 22.5 minutes

Comment: With provided start and end time it should set `hours` to 2 and `minutes` to 0. And result should be `02:00:00`

Comment: @PriceCheaperton `result` is a `TimeSpan`. Why and how do you think it should be `22.5 minutes`?

Comment: Sorry, getting confused. You are right its showing up as 02:00:00

Comment: if someone can make an answer as to how to MessageBox.show the difference in minutes then ill mark it as completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math between two `DateTime` values will produce a `TimeSpan` value. So you can just do like this:

```
(endTimeParse - startTimeParse).TotalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment, try:

```
MessageBox.Show(result.TotalMinutes.ToString())
```

Comment: I agree.  Minutes will be 0, because it is two hours and 0 minutes.  Total minutes doesn't do any arithmetic.